# RenderX XEP license doesn't work how it should

Tags: renderx

I have upgraded xep from 4.4 version to 4.30, bcs I need PDFForms.
I downloaded v4.30 from renderX page using my license.
But when I tried rendering PDFforms or BarCode with my license it didn't work.
I switched to trial license and it worked just fine.

So I think this license doesn't support new xep features.

```
  <product name="XEP">
   <limit name="server">1</limit>
  </product>
  <product name="DevKit">
   <limit name="full">1</limit>
  </product>
```

This is what the license looks like. I don't know if I have to buy new license or there is a way to **update the license.**

RenderX support won't answer me, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventualy got in contact with RenderX and they said that license key from 2005 is not available for the Interactive Forms or Barcodes add-ons.

---

**I have to buy new license and the add-ons.**